# Modify content css in a Chrome extension based on persistent settings

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple extension which adds content CSS to a web page.

I would like to have a possibility for user to modify the attributes in the content CSS so he can for example choose the color of certain elements.

In addition I would like to give him the possibility to set the URL for which the extension applies, something which I saw only set in manifest.json and I am not sure if this is possible.

How should I go about it ?

Comment: [executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi), [storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite broad and implementing it could be a challenge if your goal is to alter the styles seamlessly without flashing of the original unstyled content. Studying [Stylish-chrome](https://github.com/JasonBarnabe/stylish-chrome) or similar extensions could help.

- To allow the user edit CSS code comfortably add a JavaScript editor like Ace or CodeMirror to your extension in its toolbar popup (you'll have to save the changes on each keystroke/change) or on a separate page opened as a tab or a window-popup.
- Use [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) or [webNavigation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) to check whether the URL should be styled and inject the CSS via a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) (so that the style can be toggled) or directly with `chrome.tabs.insertCSS`.

  There's also [chrome.declarativeContent API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-RequestContentScript) with its `RequestContentScript` action which already works on stable channel of Chrome. If you decide to use it, first test its speed and reliability against the more traditional scheme above.
- The URLs and styles may be kept in [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (synchronous, thus degrades the performance) or [WebSQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) (the fastest, although "deprecated" by W3C in favor of the slower IndexedDB). You may want to keep a cached copy of the URLs in a variable for speedup.

P.S. Make sure to understand the [extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) and use the [debugger](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+debug+chrome+extensions) instead of guessing. Take a look at the official [extension samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).